# Implement ISupportIncrementalLoading in WP 8.1 MVVM app

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, infinite-scroll

I have a ListView in a WP 8.1 app that I populate with data from a web api.
My problem is that I want the list to have "infinite scrolling", in WP 8 I would have used a LongListSelector, but since that is not available in WP 8.1 I have to use a ListView and then ISupportIncrementalLoading, only problem is I really cant figure it out.

My ListView looks like this.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LatestVideos}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LatestVideoDataTemplate}">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <core:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="WindowsWorldStar.SelectedPage" />
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SendVideoMessageCommand}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListView}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

My ViewModel then looks like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Video> _latestVideo;

    public List<Video> LatestVideos
    {
        get { return _latestVideo; }
        set
        {
            _latestVideo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand SendVideoMessageCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        RefreshCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await DownloadDataAsync());

        SendVideoMessageCommand = new RelayCommand<Video>(SendVideoMessage);

        DownloadDataAsync();
    }

    private void SendVideoMessage(Video video)
    {

        Messenger.Default.Send(video);
    }


    private async Task DownloadDataAsync()
    {
        var dataServices = new DataServices();

        LatestVideos = await dataServices.GetVideoAsync("http://mywebservice.com");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

And the GetVideoAsync like this:

```
public async Task<List<Video>> GetVideoAsync(string url)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var jsonResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

        MyClass myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonResponse);

        var latestPosts = myClass.response.videos.video;
        return latestPosts;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks. :-)

Comment: To add a bit of info the web service returns 30 elements at the time so, when the user scrolls to the end of the list I want to call http://mywebservice.com/30 and then 60 and so on.

Comment: From what I get, you need to implement your own list (or extend an existing one). In this example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Data-Binding-7b1d67b5/ (in Shared Folder, IncrementalLoadingBase.cs and GeneratorIncrementalLoadingClass.cs) they implement an own List using IList, ISupportIncrementalLoading, INotifyCollectionChanged interfaces. Then  bind this observable list (it implements INotifyCollectionChanged) to your ListView in XAML

Comment: Thanks my problem is all the examples are just where they add a number to a string, and not actually contact a server and do something with the data... Why did they make something that was so simple in 8 so complicated in 8.1

Comment: This is a good example: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/implementing-the-isupportincrementalloading-interface-in-a-window-store-app/ and in the GetPagedItems method call your own webservice with the correct params to retrieve the next set of items.

Comment: @KasperSMathiesen May I ask what's the simple way to do it in WP8.0?

Comment: @yasen Using LongListSelector and ItemRealized :-)

Comment: I found this really awesome control by @TareqAteik at http://www.tareqateik.com/extendedlistview-control-for-universal-apps-pull-to-refresh-load-more-data-on-demand that is like longlistselector.